# Unexpected behaviour of Grab

Tags: 3d-view

When I grab one object to move, the world background moves and the object remains in place in the 3d view. And when I move another object it moves across my screen while the world background stands still in the 3d view. Why is that so?

Comment: Please provide some screenshots. Could it be that one object is the camera?

Comment: @Rich Sedman Definitely not the camera.

Comment: As @RichSedman said, providing some screenshots will avoid guesses. Your question is too broad as it is.

Comment: Is your view locked to the fist object?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen - You nailed it! View Lock Clear resolved my issue. Not sure how that lock to view was activated. learnt now that you can lock a view to a specific object and not the whole scene. Thank you.